# Sending Mass Texts in Android

Tags: android, sms

After users have logged into my app, I have an option to send a text to invite their friends (from mobile numbers) into the app. However, there does not appear to be a method of sending a mass text with potentially dozens of numbers without using a loop on the `.sendTextMessage` method.

What I have seen as typical:

```
  protected void sendSMSMessage() {
      Log.i("Send SMS", "");
      String phoneNo = txtphoneNo.getText().toString();
      String message = txtMessage.getText().toString();

      try {
         SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
         smsManager.sendTextMessage(phoneNo, null, message, null, null);
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS sent.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      } 

      catch (Exception e) {
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "SMS faild, please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
```

Is there another way to send mass texts without looping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right but I would suggest using [SEND ACTION](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html) as sending dozens of sms can cost user and there are application like what's app and hike, which can send or share text with friends at no extra cost.

Comment: But is there another way of sending mass tests without looping?

Comment: No there is no easy way

Answer (score 0):

You can only send one message at a time. If you do not like looping, maybe you can try recursion instead?

Comment: Can you please provide an example of this

Comment: Hello! Kind of far from my answer but I believe you want users to be able to send a text to invite their friends to use the app? You can try App Invites (https://developers.google.com/app-invites)